# DIV with Fixed Position along with Floating DIVs not working

Tags: html, css

Please look at this JsFiddle.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2tt6/)

```
<div class="main" >
    <div class="menufixedleft">
        Fixed Menu Should not Scroll
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        Main Content
    </div>

      <div class="rightsidebar">
          Right Side Bar
    </div>  
</div>
```

I am trying to have a menu div on the left fixed, content on center and sidebar on right.
It's not working when i have the center and right side bar, float left. The center div overlays the fixed div on the left.

Is my only option is to float the 2 divs(center and right sidebar) to the right ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make room for the fixed element by giving `main` either `padding-left:100px;` or `margin-left:100px` depending on how you want it to look (The 100px comes from how wide the fixed element is)

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/J2tt6/6/)

Comment: Thanks ! Never thought about padding in this situation !

Comment: No problem at all! (:

Answer (score 0):

Check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J2tt6/1/

Here's the CSS code:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.main{
    height:500px;
    width:550px;
    background:pink;
    position:relative;
}

.menufixedleft{
    height:200px;
    width:100px;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:20px;
    background:green;

}

.content{
    height:400px;
    width:200px;
    background:blue;
    position: absolute; /* should not float, as fixed elements are above everything else. */
    left: 100px;
}

.rightsidebar{
   height:200px;
    width:100px;
    background:red;
   position: absolute; /* once again, don't float. */
    left: 300px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set `position: fixed` to your left navigation, it is taken out of the layout. To keep it in, you will need to contain your menu in another element, which remains in the layout.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">

    <div class="menu">
        <div class="affix">
            Fixed Menu Should not Scroll
        </div>    
    </div>    

    <div class="content">
        Main Content
    </div>

    <div class="rightsidebar">
        Right Side Bar
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    width: 100px;
}

.affix {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
    background: green;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3f62/)

Comment: Fixed the JS Fiddle link